# Execute ruby file on passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, rack

How to execute stand alone ruby file on passenger server.

I have already looked on below link:

- [static-site-ruby](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby)
- [rack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack)

I am not expecting any configuration on file side(application).

If any thing need on passenger side, it would be fine for me, but extra configuration should not break my existing working flow (for ruby on `rails/sinatra` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at something like Sidekiq or Clockwork

https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/scheduling

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs

Hope this helps